# What to do with unused scallops' roe?

Tags: eggs, culinary-uses, seafood, shellfish, scallops

I just prepared my first scallop dish. The recipe instructed to remove roe (the orange part) before searing, as it cooks much faster than the rest of a scallop. As this was my first try, I ended up not using it for the dish.

Afterwards, I read a bit about scallop roe and it seems that many cooks actually sear it together with the rest of the scallop. Also it's a delicacy in China. Some instructions indicated that I should dry roe in oven, powder it and use it later to give extra taste to broths etc.

What is the best way to use it? If I dry and powder it, how should I store it and in which kind of dishes should I use it?

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't particularly answer the question, but the use of roe seems to fade in and out of fashion every so often. I remember 10 years ago (and back in the UK) scallops were always served with the roe, and cooked with them. Now it I haven't seen a roe anywhere near the scallops. Certainly, the more sea-food and authentic the restaurant, the more likely you are to find the roe still attached, in my experience.

Personally, I would just leave them together, and cook them still attached. The flavour is a nice contrast to the white, and it can pretty up the plate.

Doesn't directly answer your question though, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks Alex, this roe fashion-cycle is interesting nevertheless.

Answer (score 3):

I deep fry mine in tempura batter at my restaurant as
Garnish for my scallop dish, give a different texture to
The dish.

Answer (score 2):

I always use the roes, an interesting way to use them is cook them seperately, and in a different way to add another dimension to your dish, for example,  i char grill the Scallop meat, and just before serving, i pan fry the roes in garlic,lemon, chilli and parsley butter, and serve with them, on a rocket and herb salad...Fantastic!!

Answer (score 1):

Scallop roe parfait is a firm favorite in my kitchen. Gently poach the roe then blitz with soft butter and whatever spices/flavours take your fancy. Then set in a mould lined with cling film. We use small PVC pipe to set it as it's a garnish for dish. But served by itself spread on toast is a real treat for everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can use it to thicken a seafood stock or a cream sauce and give it a nice colour. It would go well also with white veal or chichen. I got the idea on the site of Chef Simon here

```
http://chefsimon.lemonde.fr/corail-saint-jacques.html
```